# Hiding HTML <object> tag which is loading a NPAPI plugin

Tags: html

I am using an  tag to load a NPAPI plugin in my HTML page. At certain point in time,
I am trying to hide the  and in order to do so, I am changing the width and height of the object to 0px using JavaScript. But this is not affecting the  tag.

Here is the syntax:

"object width='100px' height='100px' id="pluginmedia" type="application/x-wcfmedia">"

Can some one please let me know how to hide the ?

Thanks and Regards,
Souvik

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery hide() instead

```
$('#id').hide();
```

in your case it is `$('#pluginmedia').hide();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried using $('#pluginmedia').hide(); but I am getting an exception :

Comment: Sorry, my previous post was incomplete.The <object> is loaded in the <HEAD> of a HTML page. Inside that HTML page I have an iFrame which is loading a page. From a JavaScript function which is included by the HTML page loaded inside iframe, I am trying to hide  #pluginmedia. The jQuery I am using to do so is $("#pluginmedia", top.document).hide(). But I am getting an exception - TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function. It seems #pluginmedia object is not found. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Just to update further, I have removed the iframe and tried to hide the <object> which is loading the plugin, from the main page itself by calling $('#pluginmedia').hide(), but I am getting the same exception i.e.,  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function. When I am using document.getElementById("pluginmedia") and trying to print the width property, I am getting an error. It seems it is trying to make a native call of the plugin which is loaded inside the object instead of displaying the width of the object element.